# Logger requirement in Angular2 project

Tags: angular

Is there any NPM  package for logging which supports following requirements in Angular 2 projects -

1. Extending logger using Decorator pattern to push error level log to server
2. Should be able to control all logging events (framework and custom code)

   Regards,
   Naveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this angular2-logger
It has great capabilities and easy to use as well 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-logger

In case if you are interested in angular 4 or want to switch to one then this might be really helpful
For angular 4 there is another great looger  which can write logs to sever

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-logger